# Proof of Borel - Cantelli by contradiction.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, borel-cantelli-lemmas

I tried proving the following lemma: If $(A_n)_n$ is a sequence of events in a probability space s.t $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}[A_n]<\infty$, then $\mathbb{P}[\text{limsup}A_n]=0$.

My attempt:
Since $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}[A_n]<\infty$, we know that $\mathbb{P}[A_n]$ converges to $0$ as a sequence of numbers. So $\text{limsup}\mathbb{P}[A_n]=0$, so Fatou's lemma finishes the proof. Is my proof correct? I think the real question is, does $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}[A_n]<\infty$ imply convergence of the series?

Comment: Nice attempt :)

Comment: Unfortunately you have Fatou's lemma the wrong way round -- it should be $$\mathbb E[\lim\sup X_n]\geq\lim\sup\mathbb E[X_n].$$